# How to import objects from custom library with deep export

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have update my library structure (adding some directories), and now I can't import types from it.

Here is the structure of the library :

```
|-dist (builded typescript)
|-src
|--business
|---entities
|----user.ts
|----site.ts
|---usecases
|----user.usecase.ts
|----site.usecase.ts
|---entities.ts
|---usecases.ts
|--infrastructure
|---...
|--index.ts
|-package.json
```

`user.ts` and `site.ts` contains class and interface (same for `usecases` part).

`entities.ts` exports these types (same for `usecases` part) :

```
export { Site, SiteInterface } from "src/business/entities/site.js";
export { User, UserInterface } from "src/business/entities/user.js";
```

`index.ts` exports all from subdirectories :

```
export * from "src/business/entities.js";
export * from "src/business/usecases.js";
```

In `user.ts`, I can import `Site` like this : `import { Site } from "src/index.js";`

But when I install my library in another application, I get the above error `Module '"<my-lib>"' has no exported member '<my-type>'`.

I import it like this : `import { Site, User } from '@xxx/<my-lib>';`

Here are library's config files :

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "@xxx/<my-lib>",
  "version": "0.0.0-alpha.1",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "build": "npm run clean && tsc --build",
    "test": "jest",
    "circular-deps": "madge --ts-config ./tsconfig.json --extensions ts --circular ./src"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<id>/packages/npm/"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.7",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    "@types/node": "^20.2.5",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-jest-resolver": "^2.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,                                   /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
    "target": "esnext",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "module": "esnext",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",                     /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    "baseUrl": ".",                                     /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
    "paths": {                                           /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
      "@xxx/<my-lib>": ["dist/src/"],
      "@xxx/<my-lib>/*": ["dist/src/*"],
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Enable importing .json files. */
    "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
    "outDir": "dist",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "package.json"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/**/*"]
}
```

Does someone can help me to understand what I do wrong please ?

Comment: You need to generate the type definitions for the library and include it in your library package.

Comment: Hi @rveerd, thank you for your answer.
I have already `x.d.ts`and `x.d.ts.map`in my `dist` folder.
In fact I removed `types` because I do not find any documentation in official documentation (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json).

So I'va had in `package.json`:
```"types": "src/index.d.ts",```

But now : `Cannot find module '@xxx/<my-lib>' or its corresponding type declarations`.

Comment: You're src directory should never be referenced in any of your paths. Typescript does not transform these paths which means that the output in the dist folder is going to refer to the src folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found where was the problem :

Gitlab does not share workspace between stages, so it publish empty package. I have corrected this, and now it works.

I update my package following comments on my question too.

Thank you for your help @rveerd and @aluan-haddad :)